# How to add a .txt to the variable 'sec'

Tags: c++

I'm creating a project and im having a trouble in my program. I'm trying to add a ".txt" to a value of a variable so I can create a new text file.

My code goes something like this.

```
cout<<"Enter section: ";
cin>>sec;
file1.open(sec,ios::out);
```

I want to add a .txt to the variable 'sec' so that I can create a text file for it, but the program creates a file instead.

Comment: Concatenate `.txt` to your `sec` variable. `sec+=".txt"`

Comment: You should mention what type `sec` is in your post.

Comment: Im sorry, sec is in char type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cout<<"Enter section: ";
cin>>sec;
file1.open(sec,ios::out);
```

I got a solution, I concatenated the variable sec using the strcat and it goes like this.

```
cout<<"Enter section: ";
cin>>sec;
strcat(sec,".txt");
file1.open(sec,ios::out);
```

Thanks for your answers guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily concatenate values of **different types** using string streams, defined in header `sstream`.

An example, appending ".txt" after the value contained in sec, then getting the result into the `filenameWithExtension` string:

```
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << sec << ".txt";

std::string filenameWithExtension = oss.str();
```

Of course, if `sec` already is a `std:string`, you can use the operator `+` to concatenate to it, as easily as :

```
std::string filenameWithExtension = sec + ".txt";
```

Then, whichever solution you chose, you can open the file with:

```
file1.open(filenameWithExtension, ios::out);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have options:

a) Use a `ostringstream`. When you use the `operator<<` into the stream, it concatenates whatever is being passed into its internal string. To access this string, you use the method `str()`.

```
#include <sstream>

//stuff before...
std::ostringstream fname;
fname << sec << ".txt";
//then do whatever with fname.str().c_str()
```

b) Simply use the `operator+` for std::string as long as `sec` is of type `std::string`

```
cout<<"Enter section: ";
cin>>sec;
file1.open((sec + ".txt").c_str(),ios::out);
```

Comment: Okay, that can happen with short answers like that : )

Comment: @AdN - sorry I didn't mean for it to come across like I was copying.

Comment: @AdN - I can delete my answer if you want?

Comment: I would not worry that much, you seem to have done that in good faith, so I have no problems with it  ; )

Comment: @AdN - oh ok, sorry I'm new to this website so just getting used to how it works:)